# How to manage PayPal subscriptions using the API?

Tags: php, api, paypal

Does anyone know how to manage PayPal subscriptions using their API? I've read that I can use `ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus` to cancel, suspend and reactivate subscriptions, but I haven't been able to find a method to get the IDs so I'm unable to use it.

[This page](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus) says to use the method `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`'s response which contains the ID, although I'm not creating the subscriptions using the API so I wouldn't be able to do this.

Is there a API method to only get the IDs? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? On that page it says the ID needs to be the profileID, but after reading some more it seems that you can use the subscriptionID instead, so that's good. I'm just not sure how to get the subscription details and ID.

Comment: You can't manage subscriptions starting with S- through the API's (you can only cancel them). New subscriptions starting with I- can be managed through the API's, but again only limited functionality is available. For best results, create a recurring payments profile via CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and use ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus on that.

Answer (score 4):

Paypal direct payment..please change credential as your sand box provided...

```
<?php

/** DoDirectPayment NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Process a credit card payment. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('debash_1332929919_biz_api1.gmail.com');
    $API_Password = urlencode('1332929952');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('AIiPJKMw38NGZuaiDaeLWrH9x.WBAK4WXf1vh9.Y.YxEM-4DlbDLMEVe');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentType = urlencode('Sale');               // or 'Sale'
$firstName = urlencode('Debashis');
$lastName = urlencode('Banerjee');
$creditCardType = urlencode('visa');
$creditCardNumber = urlencode('4860795409505688');
$expDateMonth = '3';
// Month must be padded with leading zero
$padDateMonth = urlencode(str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$expDateYear = urlencode('2017');
$cvv2Number = urlencode('111');
$address1 = urlencode('Kaikala');
$address2 = urlencode('Hooghly');
$city = urlencode('Kaikala');
$state = urlencode('WB');
$zip = urlencode('712405');
$country = urlencode('IN');             // US or other valid country code
$amount = urlencode('71');
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr =   "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
            "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
            "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoDirectPayment', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('Direct Payment Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else  {
    exit('DoDirectPayment failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

?>
```

please visit https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

Thanks